# How to have the average of a column show up as a constant value in its own return column - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(MEM_FNAME, " ", MEM_LNAME)) AS "Full Name",
detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE,
-- Avg of detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE as it's own column
FROM membership
JOIN rental ON membership.MEM_NUM =  rental.MEM_NUM
JOIN detailrental ON rental.RENT_NUM = detailrental.RENT_NUM
WHERE detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE < 
    (SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM detailrental);
```

I'm trying to find the average of the detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE and have it display as it's own independent column, where each value is the same constant average. I'm not allowed to use GROUP BY as per the assignment's requirements.
Does anyone have any insight? I've spent a few hours studying and I'm coming up blank. Thanks in advance!!!
Language is MySQL and the platform is Mimir

Answer (score -1):

Use an average function as a Window Function.

OVER() was defined to do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(MEM_FNAME, " ", MEM_LNAME)) AS "Full Name",
    detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE,
    AVG(detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) OVER() AS AVERAGE
FROM membership
JOIN rental ON membership.MEM_NUM =  rental.MEM_NUM
JOIN detailrental ON rental.RENT_NUM = detailrental.RENT_NUM
WHERE detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE < 
    (SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM detailrental);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I'm fully understanding you but you could potentially use a subquery in your select ie. `(SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM detailrental)`.

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(MEM_FNAME, " ", MEM_LNAME)) AS "Full Name",
detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE, (SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM detailrental) as 'Daily Fee Average'
FROM membership
JOIN rental ON membership.MEM_NUM =  rental.MEM_NUM
JOIN detailrental ON rental.RENT_NUM = detailrental.RENT_NUM
WHERE detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE < 
    (SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM detailrental);
```